# @angular-devkit/build-angular install fails with EINTEGRITY error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I'm pulling an `Angular 6` project from our repo to my new laptop. My `npm` version is `6.9.0`. My `node` version is `12.4.0`. The project is an `Angular 6.0.7` project. Globally I have `Angular 6.0.8` installed, and locally (in my project), I have `Angular CLI 6.0.8` but below that where it lists the `Angular` version, it says `Angular: <error>`.

`ng serve` fails with the error `Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "my-project-path"`. Thus I tried to install this via `npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular`. However, *this* also failed with the error message:

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-spKHSBQIxxS81N/O21WmuXA2F6wppUCsutpzenOeZzOCCJ5gEfcbqJP983IrpLXzYmXnMUa6J03SubcNPdKrlg== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-spKHSBQIxxS81N/O21WmuXA2F6wppUCsutpzenOeZzOCCJ5gEfcbqJP983IrpLXzYmXnMUa6J03SubcNPdKrlg== but got sha512-2lGfU4gymmhXRUiPLeQlnlkMaSY8azJB9W8e/vFp44AlAOEvzf6XiBUoTHO9NBM4OVlehybxDM9B4SwLBh42mw==. (10271 bytes) 
...

    npm ERR! code EPROTO
    npm ERR! errno EPROTO
    npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/app-root-path failed, reason: write EPROTO 11628:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332:
    npm ERR!
```

I checked `package-lock.json` within my project, and in the `file-saver` object, the `integrity` key has `sha512-spKHSBQIxxS81N/O21WmuXA2F6wppUCsutpzenOeZzOCCJ5gEfcbqJP983IrpLXzYmXnMUa6J03SubcNPdKrlg==` which is referenced in the error message as what npm `wanted`. I don't know why it `got` the other integrity value.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this `EINTEGRITY` error?

Comment: Delete node_modules and package-lock and npm i..?